# ansible proxmox inventory plugin vault

Tags: ansible, proxmox, vault

Hope you're doing well.

I got a very basic question about ansible inventory plugins , specifically the proxmox one :

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/proxmox_inventory.html

I got this plugin setup :

```
# More complete example demonstrating the use of 'want_facts' and the constructed options
# Note that using facts returned by 'want_facts' in constructed options requires 'want_facts=true'
# my.proxmox.yml
plugin: community.general.proxmox
url: https://1.2.3.4:8006
user: root1@pve
token_id: Administrator
token_secret: REDACTEDTOKEN  
validate_certs: false
want_facts: true
# Create groups based on proxmox tags
groups:
  preprod: "'preprod' in (proxmox_tags_parsed|list)"
  prod: "'prod' in (proxmox_tags_parsed|list)"
  public: "'public' in (proxmox_tags_parsed|list)"
  lab: "'lab' in (proxmox_tags_parsed|list)"
  decom: "'decom' in (proxmox_tags_parsed|list)"

# Create hostvars
compose:
  ansible_port: 22
  ansible_user: "'ansible'"
  ansible_ssh_private_key_file: "'.ssh/ansible_srv'"
  # Parse the IP address of host (split is used to strip '/CIDR' notation)
  ansible_host: proxmox_agent_interfaces[1]["ip-addresses"][0] | default("") | split('/') | first
# Only add hosts that have an ip address
filters:
  - proxmox_agent_interfaces is defined
# For testing purposes
#strict: true
```

It works like a charm except there's something really annoying.

When i run the command to list my dynamic inventory:

```
ansible-inventory -i plugins/inventory/hypervisor.proxmox.yml --list
```

i got all the details of my servers but also my vault (in group/vars) appear as clear text in the output :

see :

```
       "proxmox_name": "b-server",                                                                                                                                                   
        "proxmox_net0": {                                                                                                                                                             
            "bridge": "vmbr0",                                                                                                                                                        
            "virtio": "02:00:00:c4:c0:ea"                                                                                                                                             
        },                                                                                                                                                                            
        "proxmox_net1": {                                                                                                                                                             
            "bridge": "vmbr1",                                                                                                                                                        
            "firewall": "1",                                                                                                                                                          
            "tag": "40",                                                                                                                                                              
            "virtio": "21:48:65:C2:31:DE"                                                                                                                                             
        },                                                                                                                                                                            
        "proxmox_node": "opz",                                                                                                                                                        
        "proxmox_numa": 0,                                                                                                                                                            
        "proxmox_ostype": "l26",                                                                                                                                                      
        "proxmox_qmpstatus": "running",                                                                                                                                               
        "proxmox_scsihw": {                                                                                                                                                           
            "disk_image": "virtio-scsi-single"                                                                                                                                        
        },   
        "proxmox_serial0": "socket",                                                                                                                                                  
        "proxmox_smbios1": {                                                                                                                                                          
            "uuid": "1bd1077a-ddd7-4419-80eb-bc3ba442a8ad"                                                                                                                            
        },                                                                                                                                                                            
        "proxmox_snapshots": [],                                                                                                                                                      
        "proxmox_sockets": 1,                                                                                                                                                         
        "proxmox_status": "running",                                                                                                                                                  
        "proxmox_tags": "preprod",                                                                                                                                                    
        "proxmox_tags_parsed": [                                                                                                                                                      
            "preprod"                                                                                                                                                                 
        ],                                                                                                                                                                            
        "proxmox_vga": "qxl",                                                                                                                                                         
        "proxmox_virtio0": {                                                                                                                                                          
            "disk_image": "local:167/vm-167-disk-0.raw",                                                                                                                              
            "iothread": "1",                                                                                                                                                          
            "size": "42G"                                                                                                                                                             
        },                                                                                                                                                                            
        "proxmox_vmgenid": "38e3bfaf-9695-46c5-804b-d7dfa279c7d9",                                                                                                                    
        "proxmox_vmid": 167,                                                                                                                                                          
        "proxmox_vmtype": "qemu",                                                                                                                                                     
        "vault_6admin_password": "REDACTEDPASSWORD",                                                                                                                   
        "vault_admin1_password": "REDACTEDPASSWORD",                                                                                                                          
        "vault_root_password": "REDACTEDPASSWORD"                                                                   
    },
```

Can someone explain to my why the plugin is decrypting all the vault in the output ?
Can i just simply prohibit this behavior ?
Do i need no_log or something similar ?

Thank you very much for your lights.